# Is there an easy way to convert this API get request into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-requests

I am trying to get this US Census Bureau api data get request into a dataframe and thought that it was a list of list but is showing up as a NoneType. Is there a way to make this into a dataframe that could be easily exported into a CSV file?

```
import request

# The Basic API Request:

# Build base URL
HOST = "https://api.census.gov/data"
year = "2010"
dataset = "dec/sf1"
base_url = "/".join([HOST, year, dataset])

# Specify Census variables and other predicates
get_vars = ["NAME","P013001","P037001"]
predicates = {}
predicates["get"] = ",".join(get_vars)
predicates["for"] = "state:*"

# Execute the request, examine text of response object
data = requests.get(base_url, params=predicates)
print(data.text)
```

This does produce the following output:

```
[["NAME","P013001","P037001","state"],
["Alabama","37.9","3.02","01"],
["Alaska","33.8","3.21","02"],
["Arizona","35.9","3.19","04"],
...
["Wyoming","36.8","2.96","56"],
["Puerto Rico","36.9","3.17","72"]]
```

Comment: can you tell me what's the data type it returned when you call the api? what does data.text return?

Comment: type(data)  = requests.models.Response;     type(data.text)  = str; 
    type(print(data.text)) = NoneType

Comment: Then it seems you need to look into why the api is returning nothing for you first.

Comment: If I do "print(data.text)" it does produce the above result...[added to submission]. This looks like a list of list but when I run pd.DataFrame(data) it produces something funky and pd.DataFrame(data.text) errors out with "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Comment: what kind of format does `pd.DataFrame()` want, then convert the data into this format. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Your data.type is actually a string representation of list of list. So you need to convert it to standard csv first or a list of list data structure first. One way is to replace all the `[]`, then it should turn into a valid csv for your DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.text` is a string, so you could parse it through json, try this

```
import json
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data.text)[1:], columns=['NAME', 'P013001', 'P037001', 'state'])
```

and you'll get something similar to the image below.
[image]